# Sharing and Import image in android using Google Photo API android

Tags: java, android, google-photos, google-photos-api

I want to use Google photo API in my application for sharing image using Google photo API. I have created client id in credential section.

From here I am stuck how to use it and how to open Google photo and select image from there for sharing purpose. I have to enter in Google photo using view touch once I enter in Google photo I can select image and return with selected images.

Comment: You can refer google codelabs : https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/google-photos-sharing/#0

Comment: you should provide the relevant code for any attempts you have had at solving this